# Ordering logs by embedded timestamp vs Heroku timestamp Logentries

Tags: heroku, logentries

Is there a way to change the settings within Logentries on Heroku to sort the logs based upon the embedded log timestamp vs the timestamp that Heroku displays?

Currently having issues with our logs being completely out of order when we are letting the logs sort by Heroku timestamp. There seems to be a pretty big lack of options from what I can see in the portal.

Comment: Can you clarify some things? Are the logs intended to be submitted in temporal sequence, but then you find that they are not? Or are these log events that you expect to get submitted in non-temporal sequence, but then wish to sort on a field?

Comment: I would expect them to be sorted in the order in which the events occur, but it either seems like Heroku/Logentries is receiving the events in a strange order, or there is some sort of default non time based sorting happened. When I run the jobs that produce the logs and just view them in the console the order is correct.

Comment: Parchambeau, can you run `heroku logs -t` to see the live tail? Does the sequence correspond to what you see on logentries?

Comment: I ended up just moving over to "loggly" and they have the ability to sort the logs based upon the embedded date stamp. Thank you for your help though, much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, parchambeau, but I'm curious what the result was. I suspect the logs events aren't actually being created in the intended order, and checking the heroku logs directly would let you confirm whether this is true. You'd probably want to fix this regardless of which service you use -- unless the timestamp is intended to indicate the "start" of an event that finishes asynchronously and is only logged then? (e.g., http req data that needs to include the response time)